# Global go-flag AddCommand clarification and/or example

Tags: go, go-flag

In my early days of learning Go and trying to use package `github.com/jessevdk/go-flags`.  I checked the Fly example referenced in another `go-flags` thread, but it apparently does not use `AddCommand` (at least per my grep).

The godoc article recommends defining a global parser instance and to implement each command in a separate file.  Each of those command files should define a go init function which calls AddCommand on the global parser.

Making my parser global was easy enough.  Confused on the `init()` setups:

1)  My understanding is that `init()` order execution is random, other than your main's init running last.

2)  If so, I can't ensure that my `NewParser()` call in my configuration code has been called prior my AddCommand() calls.

3)  My code compiles, but a --help doesn't show any defined commands, making me think that indeed, the `AddCommand()` was called before the `NewParser()` 
/* Just a guess */

4)  QED I'm confused!

Does anybody have a recommended example I could go learn from?